# pmdaccess2.dll is missing even though code compiles with no error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, linker

My code compiles correctly but when I start without debugging it gives the following error:

```
pmdaccess2.dll is missing
```

I have provided the link to this dll in the `Linker->general` section however I get this error. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
I am using Visual Studio 2015 64bit in Windows 10 and my PMD camera is connected to USB3. 
[image][image]

Comment: A dll doesn't get linked (that's what the .lib is for), so adding it to Linker shouldn't be too useful. Easier to put the dll somewhere on the PATH, or alter PATH to add its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic library is linked to at runtime. The library needs to be located in the same directory as the executable or in a directory specified in the PATH environment variable.